# Lexical Relationships

Tags: lexical-semantics

How can I define the lexical/semantic relationship between a noun X and a modifier + noun X?
e.g. a girl/ a beautiful girl; a city/ a big city. Is it a case of hyperonimy/superordination?

Comment: It's not a lexical distinction. It's a syntactic one.

Comment: @jlawler: but there is some sort of semantic relationship, which the OP is also asking about. I doubt if it is possible to characterise the relationship in general in any meaningful way, though.

Answer (score 1):

1. some linguists see a distinction between A) 'descriptive' (selecting one of many possible features) and B) 'classificatory' (specifying a subset of the class) modifiers, and would say that 'beautiful' and 'big' are descriptive (eg Halliday 'epithet' vs 'classifier')
2. your suggestion of hyperonomy/superordination would place 'beautiful, big' in B), i.e meaning that 'beautiful girls' are a subset of 'girls' and that 'big cities' are a subset of 'cities'
3. there is also an implicit notion that 'descriptive' = 'subjective/personal opinion', and 'classificatory' = 'objective/consensus opinion'; so many linguists would disagree with your suggestion that 'beautiful, big' are 'objective/consensus' classes
4. from my corpus linguistics perspective, 'beautiful girl and 'big city' are frequent collocations (strictly speaking, i should check the statistics in a large general English corpus before asserting this, so... http://corpus2.byu.edu/glowbe/, a corpus of 1.9 billion words, tells me that the most frequent modifiers occurring one word before 'girl' in 226047 authentic text examples are: little, young, old, baby, teenage, beautiful; so beautiful is the 6th most frequent collocate)... so i would suggest that 'beautiful girl' is a usage-based/consensus unit of language, which draws on both the descriptive and classificatory functions/purposes of language?
5. 'beautiful girl and big city' cannot be analysed further without knowing more details about the contextual occurrence of this collocation - eg in which specific text and genre of text, written/spoken by whom, in what historical/social circumstance, etc?

Comment: Thank you. I'm taking into analysis the lexis of a literary text. As most of the words belong to a few semantic fields, I'm trying to describe the lexical relationship between these terms. They are sometimes syononyms, hyponyms, antonyms, but other times the same word is directly repeated and only the preceding modifier actually changes. Of course, modifiers add new meaning to the given word. How can I define this type of relationship between words in a text? Many thanks, T.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperonymy and other sense relations are not usually applied to adjective + noun combinations (expections are made where the combination is lexicalised, such as *White House*). Instead, your examples can be analysed by comparing the sets of entities they refer to. The phrase with a modifier can refer only to a subset of the entities that the noun without modifier can refer to.

Some cities are big, and not all cities are big. *a city* can then refer to any city from the set of all existing cities, while *a big city* can only refer to a subset of all cities - namely those of a certain size.